# Ensure that urlpatterns is list of path() and/or re_path() instances

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

What's wrong with my urlpatterns?

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns +=  static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT),
```

**ERRORS:**

```
?: (urls.E004) Your URL pattern [<URLPattern '^media/(?P<path>.*)$'>] is invalid. 
 Ensure that urlpatterns is a list of path() and/or re_path() instances.
```

Comment: can you show full urls.py code and your settings.py where you have declared **MEDIA_URL**